# $unset specification must be a string or an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-compass

I have documents in this structure:

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"..."
   },
   "Index":0,
   "KeyIndex":"...",
   "SerialNumber":"...",
   "Tests":[
      {
         "TestName":"...",
         "Status":"...",
         "Steps":[
            {
               "LowLimit":"X",
               "HighLimit":"Y",
               "Result":"Z"
            },
            {
               "LowLimit":"X",
               "HighLimit":"Y",
               "Result":"Z"
            }
         ],
         "Logs":[
            {
               "Type":"Info",
               "Message":"..."
            },
            {
               "Type":"Warning",
               "Message":"..."
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "TestName":"...",
         "Status":"...",
         "Steps":[
            {
               "LowLimit":"X",
               "HighLimit":"Y",
               "Result":"Z"
            }
         ],
         "Logs":[
            {
               "Type":"Info",
               "Message":"..."
            },
            {
               "Type":"Info",
               "Message":"..."
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

As you can see, The `Tests` property is an array where each object has its own properties, Which 2 of them are arrays them self.
I want a stage which removes from all objects which are in the test array the logs property.

The result should be like this:

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"..."
   },
   "Index":0,
   "KeyIndex":"...",
   "SerialNumber":"...",
   "Tests":[
      {
         "TestName":"...",
         "Status":"...",
         "Steps":[
            {
               "LowLimit":"X",
               "HighLimit":"Y",
               "Result":"Z"
            },
            {
               "LowLimit":"X",
               "HighLimit":"Y",
               "Result":"Z"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "TestName":"...",
         "Status":"...",
         "Steps":[
            {
               "LowLimit":"X",
               "HighLimit":"Y",
               "Result":"Z"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I am using compass to build the aggregation, I chose $unset stage and tried:

```
/**
 * fields: The field name(s).
 */
{
  "$Tests.Logs"
}
```

And:

```
/**
 * fields: The field name(s).
 */
{
  ["$Tests.Logs"]
}
```

which says: *`Stage must be a properly formatted document.`*

And:

```
/**
 * fields: The field name(s).
 */
{
  "$Tests.Logs":1
}
```

which says: *`$unset specification must be a string or an array .`*

Comment: see [$unset aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unset/) stage, you can either just specify one field in string like `"Tests.Logs"` or you can specify multiple in array `["Tests.Logs"]`

Comment: It says: Stage must be a properly formatted document. When I do that

Comment: yes this is not formatted `{  "$Tests.Logs":1 }` as per `$unset` syntax just try only `"Tests.Logs"`. remove object

Comment: I also tried your suggestion {
  "Tests.Logs"
}.  which says "Stage must be a properly formatted document."

Comment: please read the documentation provided in first comment, just use only string `"Tests.Logs"`, remove everything and don't wrap in object => remove this `{ }`.

Comment: Oh ok. It Works now. Thanks